# calculating total time of an event based on condition

Tags: mysql

I have a following table

```
CREATE TABLE log (  
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
     keyNo VARCHAR(16),  
     date DATE NOT NULL,
     time TIME NOT NULL,
     t1Event VARCHAR(255),
     t2Event VARCHAR(255),  
     PRIMARY KEY  (id)  
)
```

I have table rows in following manner

```
1 205 2018-07-10 12:01 Lclosed keyout
2 205 2018-07-10 12:02 Lclosed keyout
3 205 2018-07-10 12:03 Lclosed keyinside
4 205 2018-07-10 12:44 Lclosed keyout
5 205 2018-07-10 13:02 Lclosed keyinside
```

This table I got after executing following query

```
Select * from reportsuser where keyNo = '205' and date = '2018-07-10' and t1Event='Lclosed'
```

No I want to calculate the total time for which the key was out which can be calulated by first `keyout` event and first `keyinside` after first `keyout` event. Like this I want to calculate total time by summing up all such time difference for example in above case I want `(3 - 1) + (5 - 4)` in terms of `sno`. How can I achieve this mysql query? What will be the best method since time period for such queries can be month or year?

Comment: Give us couple of records example data so we can better a beter feeling for the data. Not the resultset from a query.. we totally missing the `keyinside` events.. Some give us a ascii data table (text formatted) with a expected results based on the example data

Comment: Sorry for confusion this is actual dataset for particular `key=205` and for `date=2018-07-10`. `keyinside` is the name of event when key reached inside locker` while 'keyout` is the event when key was out of locker. I want to calculate time difference between first key out and first key inside and after that it repeats in similar fashion.

Comment: You can use running total to get this elapsed time, whereby the subsequent keyout time differences are added to the counter, while the keyinside ones are subtracted. There are quite a few questions on running totals (or cumulative sums) within MySQL here on SO. That's where I would start looking for a solution.

Comment: Tip: Store date and time as a single entity

Comment: Due to some restriction I can't so I will have to go with date and time as separate entity

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE log (  
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
     dt DATETIME NOT NULL,
     status VARCHAR(255),  
     PRIMARY KEY  (id)  
);

INSERT INTO log VALUES
(1, '2018-07-10 12:01:00' ,'keyout'),
(2, '2018-07-10 12:02:00' ,'keyout'),
(3, '2018-07-10 12:03:00' ,'keyinside'),
(4, '2018-07-10 12:44:00' ,'keyout'),
(5, '2018-07-10 13:02:00' ,'keyinside');


SELECT MIN(dt) dto 
     , dti
     , SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(dti)-TIME_TO_SEC(MIN(dt))) diff
  FROM 
     (  SELECT x.dt
             , MIN(y.dt) dti
          FROM log x
          JOIN log y ON y.dt > x.dt 
           AND y.status = 'keyinside'
         WHERE x.status = 'keyout'
         GROUP 
            BY x.dt
     ) a
 GROUP
    BY dti;

    +---------------------+---------------------+----------+
    | dto                 | dti                 | diff     |
    +---------------------+---------------------+----------+
    | 2018-07-10 12:01:00 | 2018-07-10 12:03:00 | 00:02:00 |
    | 2018-07-10 12:44:00 | 2018-07-10 13:02:00 | 00:18:00 |
    +---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```